Issues with Apostrophes and Mixed-Case Sentences Using mfirstuc Package
I'm using the mfirstuc package for sentence case formatting and encountering two problems:

Capitalizing Phrases with Apostrophes: I need phrases with apostrophes to be correctly capitalized, where words after the apostrophe are also capitalized. For example, jardins fabuleux d'atlas should become Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas.
Mixed-Case Sentence Capitalization: I want to capitalize the first letter of each word in a mixed-case sentence, making the rest of the letters lowercase. For instance, sOmE mIxEd cAsE sEnTeNcE should transform into Some Mixed Case Sentence. My attempt to use \ecapitalisewords with \MakeLowercase like this:

\ecapitalisewords{\MakeLowercase{sOmE mIxEd cAsE sEnTeNcE}}

results in the entire sentence being lowercase. It seems like the \ecapitalisewords command is never executed on the output of \MakeLowercase.
Here's a MWE demonstrating both issues:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\gMFUnocap{d'}

\begin{document}

% Issue 1
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\capitalisewords{jardins fabuleux d'atlas}

% Issue 2
% Desired output: Some Mixed Case Sentence
\ecapitalisewords{\MakeLowercase{sOmE mIxEd cAsE sEnTeNcE}}

% Combined issues
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\capitalisewords{jArDiNs fAbUlEuX d'atLaS}

\end{document}

I'm specifically using the mfirstuc package because it provides the \gMFUnocap{⟨word⟩} command to exclude certain words from being case-changed, which I need for other parts of my document. However, if there are alternative packages that can solve these issues while also providing similar functionality to \MFUnocap{⟨word⟩}, I'm open to suggestions.
I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving these capitalization issues. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

You can use a regex to replace instances of d' with d\MFUwordbreak{\textquoteright}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\gMFUnocap{d}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \mycroft_wbapostrophe:
  {
    \MFUwordbreak { \textquoteright }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \mycroft_lowerthencaps:n
  {
    \ecapitalisewords { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycaps}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { d' } { d\c{mycroft_wbapostrophe:} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:NV \ecapitalisewords \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylowerthencaps}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { d' } { d\c{mycroft_wbapostrophe:} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:NV \mycroft_lowerthencaps:n \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Issue 1
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\mycaps{jardins fabuleux d'atlas}

% Issue 2
% Desired output: Some Mixed Case Sentence
\mylowerthencaps{sOmE mIxEd cAsE sEnTeNcE}

% Combined issues
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\mylowerthencaps{jArDiNs fAbUlEuX d'atLaS}

\end{document}


You can define a command \addapostropherule{<letters>} to apply this more generally.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \mycroft_wbapostrophe:
  {
    \MFUwordbreak { \textquoteright }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \mycroft_lowerthencaps:n
  {
    \ecapitalisewords { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
  }
\tl_new:N \g_mycroft_nocaps_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\addapostropherule}{m}
  {
    \gMFUnocap{#1}
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_mycroft_nocaps_tl { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycaps}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mycroft_nocaps_tl
      {
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { ##1' } { ##1\c{mycroft_wbapostrophe:} } \l_tmpa_tl
      }
    \exp_args:NV \ecapitalisewords \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylowerthencaps}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_mycroft_nocaps_tl
      {
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { ##1' } { ##1\c{mycroft_wbapostrophe:} } \l_tmpa_tl
      }
    \exp_args:NV \mycroft_lowerthencaps:n \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addapostropherule{d}
\addapostropherule{l}
\addapostropherule{qu}
\addapostropherule{s}

\begin{document}

% Issue 1
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\mycaps{jardins fabuleux d'atlas}

\mycaps{la maison qu'il a construite}

% Issue 2
% Desired output: Some Mixed Case Sentence
\mylowerthencaps{sOmE mIxEd cAsE sEnTeNcE}

% Combined issues
% Desired output: Jardins Fabuleux d'Atlas
\mylowerthencaps{jArDiNs fAbUlEuX d'atLaS}

\end{document}


That's a great idea. Thanks

Can your this be extended to handle other French contractions with apostrophes, like l', qu', and s', in addition to handling d'? @mbert

@Mycroft_47 Yes, I will update the answer later. I've also found a bug, \mycaps{d'atlas} still capitalizes the first letter. Working on it

@Mycroft_47 I guess this is actually intended behavior of mfirstuc. See the example with \MFUnocap{the} on page 18 of the documentation. Is the French standard to write D'Atlas if it's the start of a sentence?

Yes, that's the standard in French as well. As you mentioned, this is not a bug; it is intended behavior. The documentation clearly states, Some words typically shouldn’t have their case changed unless they occur at the start. @mbert

@Mycroft_47 Makes sense. See updated answer

Great answer, thanks again @mbert

May I ask one last thing, please? When incorporating your answer into my code, I found that the \mylowerthencaps command doesn't apply the apostrophe rule to some text stored in a variable. How can I fix this? You can find a working example here. It is just the updated version of your answer, where I have added how the variable I use to store text is defined. @mbert

@Mycroft_47 The argument is not being expanded enough. Try something like \NewDocumentCommand{\emylowerthencaps}{m}{\exp_args:Ne\mylowerthencaps{#1}}

The issue was indeed an expansion problem, thanks for the fix! @mbert
